# Data Filter in Journey Builder only only goes until 2015

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I tried to put a Decision Split where i wanted to create flows to olders people in my Data Extension. I noticed that there is no year less than 2015. Is only in my ORG? is there any way to get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes even I tried to check the above in platform and I noticed that **2015** is the least year we can select!

However if you wish to select an age less than 2015, you can select the "is before" operator!

[image]

I guess this seems to be UI bug! where in I found a work around, where in I was able to navigate before 2015, by navigating backwards as below!
[image]